# Invalidate or remove rejected build on App Store to reuse a build number

Tags: ios

If I get an email regarding a rejected build e.g. `Missing Purpose String in Info.plist File`.

Then once I resolve the issue, is it mandatory to increment the build number? Or can I remove or invalidate the previous build so I can reuse the build number used for the rejected build?

Context:
I am building a react native app and would like to keep the build number (for iOS) and version code (for Android) be the same

Answer (score 2):

To upload app on the app store the **pair(version,buildNumber)** should be unique.
so if your particular build is rejected by app store and you want to use the same version then you can increase the build number  and upload the new build again.

These the important point to remember:

1. If current pair(version,build) is (2.2,1) then you can upload the build by updating the pair as (2.2,2)....
2. Version (CFBundleShortVersionString) must be in ascending sequential order.
3. Build number (CFBundleVersion) must be in ascending sequential order.

[To read more about Version and build number in iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2420/_index.html)

Answer (score 1):

You should always consider to update your build number for new uploads, as only your version stays the same and this way you can track the correct build.

e.g. your app is at `1.0.0` and you upload build `1`.
Now this build gets rejected for any reason and you need to fix the issue and upload another build.

This new build should have build number `2` otherwise you can't tell for sure it is the updated one.

In comparison, you do not have to update the version number at this point (at least if you are using [semantic versioning](https://semver.org/)) as you didn't release anything yet.